# User details are not storing in Auth component in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I am using CakePHP 2.9 version. `$this->Auth-login()` function in Userscontroller doesnt get username. even though my database(user) have 'username' and 'password' field. It is redirecting to else statement.

**UsersController:**

```
public $components = array('Paginator','Auth','Session','Flash');

    public function beforeFilter() {
        $this->Auth->allow('login','logout');
    }

    public function login(){
if($this->request->is('post')){         
    $this->set('user1',$this->Auth->request);
    if($this->Auth->login()){
        return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect(['controller'=>'accessors','action'=>'index']));
    }
    else{
        $this->Flash->set('Please check with username and password.');
    }   }}
```

**login.ctp**

```
echo $this->Form->create('User');

echo $this->Form->input('username',$options=array('div'=>array('class'=>'input text required'),'type'=>'text','autocomplete'=>'off'));

echo $this->Form->input('password',$options=array('div'=>'input password required'));

echo $this->Form->button('Submit', $options=array('type'=>'submit'));

echo $this->Form->button('Reset', $options=array('type'=>'reset')).'</br>';
```

[Here is the screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_yFC5soppIQMWthRzZNTno3S1k/view?usp=sharing) of variables with assigned values captured through DebugKit

Can someone tell me where did i make mistake ?

Comment: is your password hashed ? and did you mention that in appController ?

Comment: no, I am not using password hashing in appController or any class.

Comment: post the debug value of this->request->data..

Comment: Debug value of $request->data
>User(array) 
     username admin
     password tiger